# How do I calculate the percentage of one column to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I have a query:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBMITDATE as date) as 'Date'

,COUNT(*) as [Tickets Submitted]
,SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Tickets Closed]

FROM Table1

    WHERE SUBMITDATE >= '2015-05-29'
      AND SUBMITDATE < '2015-06-03'


GROUP BY CAST(SUBMITDATE as date)
```

which produces the following result:

```
Date        Tickets Submitted   Tickets Closed
2015-05-29  1062                1040
2015-05-30  429                 416
2015-05-31  260                 250
2015-06-01  705                 654
2015-06-02  556                 515
2015-06-03  508                 452
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of tickets Closed.
 [Tickets Closed] divided by [Tickets Submitted].

When I try adding: `,SUM((CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*)) as [Percentage of Tickets Closed]`

I get the following error:

"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Can anyone help?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the COUNT inside the SUM.   Try like this:

```
,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN mrSTATUS = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS float)/CAST(COUNT(*) AS float) as [Percentage of Tickets Closed]
```

The SUM and COUNT functions will produce integers, which means the division will also result in an integer.   CAST them as floats to get a fraction instead.

Comment: This gives me just a bunch of 0 (zeros) in that column

Comment: Then try casting as a float.   I will update my answer.

Comment: you may also want to add * 100 to get percentage.

Comment: Using CAST as FLOAT works.. thank you, Tab.  Adding the (* 100) also gets that number I'm looking for.  Thank you, Tim :)  Can I encapsulate that entire line with a DECIMAL command to get the number down to just 2 decimals?  Thanks again fellas!!

Comment: Sure you could cast as DECIMAL(4,2) instead of float to get only xx.xx

Answer (score 0):

```
,CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(*) as FLOAT)*100 as DECIMAL(5,2)) as [% of Tickets Closed]
```

is what I was looking for.

Here are the results I get:

```
Date        Tickets Submitted   Tickets Closed  % of Tickets Closed
2015-05-29  1062                1047            98.59
2015-05-30  428                 418             97.66
2015-05-31  260                 253             97.31
2015-06-01  703                 669             95.16
2015-06-02  555                 517             93.15
2015-06-03  507                 463             91.32
```